# How can i fix "(df[df['id']==id_value].name == 1).any()" 'The truth value of a Series is ambiguous error'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code will run fine in most cases in python(jupyter), but
I'm getting an error from time to time in my web app using the following code:

```
 if (df[df['id']==id_value].name == 1).any():
```

I haven't been able to determine in which case the error occurred because it was used in web page.
In what cases can the famous error below occur?

```
the truth value of a series is ambiguous. use a.empty a.bool() a.item() a.any() or a.all()
```

I've tried many cases (eg id=[1,1], name=[1,1]) but jupyter doesn't give me an error.

I have no idea what the heck is the reason.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to `isin` + `loc`

```
 if (df.loc[df['id'].isin(id_value),'name']== 1).any():
```